# Will partitioning in Google BigQuery improve join performance?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with around 800k rows (which I didn't think is a lot). It is created from a series of other tables. I am then joining this table with another table of about 5M rows (using the python client), but it appears to be taking forever. In the NoSQL and SQL world I would create an index. In BQ, I think this is a partition or can I create an Index.

I'm using python and the following to create a table

```
query = """
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `{table_name}` AS
WITH get_all_affiliate AS (
""".format(table_name=table_name)
```

and

```
query += """
    ) SELECT * from get_all_table
    """
```

and then

```
response = client.query(query).result()
```

How can I easily CAST and also perform some indexing/partition on one field that is a string, but can be recast as an Integer?

Comment: partition helps to reduce query data, but if both tables needs to be joined it does not help. Think of that BigQuery does a join by combining all elements. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute
Cast(string_column_A as int64) as tempory_column_A

Comment: Hi @Samuel, you may post your comment as an answer since it already explains the logic in using Partition and `JOIN` when it comes to query optimization.

Answer (score 1):

As @Samuel mentioned in comments, Partition can be used to optimize a query in BigQuery. However, if both tables need to be joined, it does not help since `JOIN` will combine all of both tables' elements which contradicts the purpose of Partition. For more information, you may refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/%E2%80%A6).

You can use below for casting a string and recast as integer.

```
Cast(string_column_A as int64) as tempory_column_A
```

Posting the answer as *community wiki* for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.